# Asp.Net - Button in repeater doesn't work when browser is set to no javascript - help!

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, repeater

I have a button in a rather complex repeater, it has to have `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` or I get the error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

So I've been using the `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` but I find that the button doesn't submit if Javascript is disabled on the browser.

Any suggestions?

Here's all the markup of the repeater, the button in question is btnAddToCart:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr><td>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
<div style="border-color:Black;border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
<table width="100%">
  <tr><td colspan="2">
    <div style="border-bottom-width:thin;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:gray;background-color:#ffe3a6">
    <table width="100%" >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="header" style="text-align:left;">
            <a href="<%# GetMoreInfoLink((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem) %>" class="productlink">
              <%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).ItemCode %> : <%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Name %>
            </a>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="header" style="text-align:right;"><%# string.Format("{0:C}", ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Price)%></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table></div>
  </td></tr>
  <tr valign="middle">
    <td style="text-align:center;padding-left: 5px;">
      <a href="<%# GetMoreInfoLink((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem) %>" class="productlink" style="color: #FFFFE2">
        <img src='<%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Thumb_link %>' alt="" />
      </a>
      <br />
      <a class="main" href="<%# GetMoreInfoLink((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem) %>">More Info</a>
    </td>
    <td >
      <div align="center">
      <table width="90%"><tr><td style="text-align:center">
        <span style="text-align:justify"><%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Short_desc %></span>
      </td></tr></table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left">
      <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" Text="Edit"  
        Visible="<%# IsEditButtonVisible() %>"
        PostBackUrl="<%# GetEditButtonLink((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem) %>" CausesValidation="False" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
      <table align="right" cellspacing="10px"><tr>
      <td id="Td1" runat="server" visible="<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Docs_link) %>">
        <a class="main" href="<%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Docs_link %>">Documentation</a>
      </td>
      <%-- <td><a href="">Demo</a></td> --%>
      <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" UseSubmitBehavior="False" 
          OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" 
          CommandArgument='<%# ((ProductRecord)Container.DataItem).Id %>'
        />
      </td>

      </tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <SeparatorTemplate>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
  </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

PS: If you care to see what the page/code looks like and want to test it - [here](http://searisen.com/products/).

Comment: You could set `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>`, but this wouldn't come highly recommended.

Comment: That is actually the expected the behaviour as Asp.Net uses Javascript to post back. Maybe you could look at creating basic html submit buttons and managing the postback youself?

Comment: @Craig Well my button on the next deeper product page that doesn't use a repeater and doesn't have the `UseSubmitBehavior=false` works just fine.   I may have to remove that and do what Mr. Disappointment says, though its not recommended as the error says, so I'd like to avoid it.  Worse case senario is to do a `<noscript>` block and put a message to go there to add, but thats ugly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button that requires the JavaScript is of type `button`, whereas the button that doesn't (on your product detail page) is of type `submit` - the latter uses the default submit behaviour for the HTML form whereas the former requires JavaScript to initiate a submission in order to identify the control that raised the postback.

As @Craig says, this is by design - ASP.NET uses JavaScript for postbacks in situations such as yours.

Your login page buttons and parts of your cart won't work without JavaScript either, so this may be a bigger redesign than you planned if you're really keen to offer a scriptless experience.  You can use multiple HTML forms (without `runat="server"`) on an ASP.NET page so you may have to go down that route and split each product into its own form, which would then enable you to use the default HTML form submission.

It's probably worth assessing your target audience and also having a quick read of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript

**Edit:** and here's a list of [ASP.NET controls that use client-side script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178206.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Town, just yesterday someone came to the site and I had a blank page for the home page because of the lack of no-javascript handling, so this is definitely a work in progress to fix all that.  Thankfully he dug deeper, found my support by viewing the source and reported it!

Comment: The markup on the detail page is exactly the same minus the UseSubmitBehavior=false line, so it must be something that Asp.Net does by making it of type submit, I'll have to look more closely.  And yes I'd noticed the Register button doesn't work on the Login page, arg!  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Chuck Savage: If you've got no home page then I guess not being able to add things to a shopping cart becomes a bit of a side issue! ;)

Comment: @Chuck Savage: My assumption is that as it's the only button on the  product details page then it'll take on the default HTML `input type="submit"`, therefore negating the need for JavaScript in that instance.

Comment: @Town thanks, that makes sense.  I'd fixed the no home page problem yesterday, and was working through more problems today.

Comment: @Town thanks again, I ended up creating a component that detects no javascript and binds to the visible property of the buttons.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785214/asp-net-detect-no-javascript-on-page-renamed-title/5810923#5810923 for the code.